# Acceder a un dato dentro de un objeto json (no array)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Estoy trabajando con angularjs, Tengo una consulta para que me traiga un usuario por numero de documento, me devuelve un json con los datos, lo que necesito es acceder al dato idUsuario de ese objeto json para inyectarlo en otra parte,  al  dar un console.log en la variable a la que asigno el resultado de la consulta, muestra esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he intentado con vm.data.idUsuario, vm.data["idUsuario"], pero me dice que es undefined, trabajo con javascript, ¿cual es la forma correcta de hacerlo?.

este es el codigo

```
var vm = this;   
vm.user = {};  
vm.user = Usuarios.queryBydocuni({
                    query: data[i].documento //esta parte es para sacar el parámetro de consulta de otra parte

});
 vm.id = vm.user["idUsuario"];
console.log(vm.id);
```

Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

Comment: ¿vm es la variable que imprimes por pantalla?

Comment: la variable es data, vm es solo un identificador.  vm.data seria lo que contiene el objeto json o el resultado de la consulta, es un solo registro.

Comment: Entonces bastaría simplemente con utilizar `data["idUsuario"]` para recuperar su valor.

Comment: me lo marca como undefined. lo tengo asi

Comment: vm.user = Usuarios.queryBydocuni({
                    query: data[i].documento
                });
                console.log(vm.user);
                vm.id = vm.user["idUsuario"];

Comment: la primera es la consulta, lo asigno a vm.user y luego trato de sacar el idUsuario.

Comment: `console.log(vm.user)` es lo que te devuelve los datos?

Comment: si, es para ver si me traía algo, devuelve lo de la imagen.

Comment: ¿Y si haces console.log de vm.id te devuelve undefined?

Comment: exacto eso no hay nada

Comment: Prueba a hacer `console.log(vm.user["idUsuario"])` a ver si te devuelve datos de esta forma. En principio no te debería salir undefined.

Comment: me marca undefined sale esto no existe el identificador

Comment: cuando hago console.log(vm.user) me imprime lo de la imagen, al tratar de acceder al campo idUsuario marca undefined...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Actualizada

Lo que pasa es que tu código actual intenta leer sobre el objeto vm.user antes de que la respuesta llegue desde la consulta, lo que necesitas es esperar a que llegue la respuesta así entonces podrás asignar el valor a vm.user y posteriormente usarla más adelante, intenta poner tu código así y me comentas:

```
var vm = this;   
Usuarios.queryBydocuni({
  // Esta parte es para obtener el parámetro de la consulta de otra parte
  query: data[i].documento
}).$promise.then(function(usr){
   vm.user = usr;
   vm.id = vm.user["idUsuario"];
   console.log(vm.id);
})
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64571/discussion-on-answer-by-yefry-lopez-acceder-a-un-dato-dentro-de-un-objeto-json).

Answer (score 0):

Primero debugea el objeto con `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` para ver que estas recibiendo. Luego simplemente en el lugar adonde lo estes recibiendo asignaselo a una variable.

```
let id;
id = data.json().idUsuario ;
return id// devolvería lo que solicitas.
```

Comment: Al hacer ese console me devuelve unas llaves vacías { }, como si no hubiera nada... ¿eso que significa?.

Comment: sube el código de la consulta, significa que te esta llegando vació el objeto.

Comment: es una consulta jpql, es esta : SELECT u FROM Usuarios u WHERE u.numDocumento = :numDocumento

Comment: la sintaxis es correcta, probaste esa query en la bd?

Comment: si me devuelve los datos, la cosa es que al darle console.log en vm.user que es la variable donde guardo el resultado de la consulta, me la imprime, imprime lo que se ve en la imagen que adjunté, pero al tratar de acceder al campo idUsuario que es lo que requiero me marca undefined.

Comment: disculpa, estaba mal mi respuesta, prueba console.log(JSON.stringify(vm.data)) .Arriba te han dejado la respuesta, retorna vm.data["idUsuario"]

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(vm.user)) me devuelve { }, console.log(vm.user) me devuelve lo de la imagen que adjunté... no entiendo el problema.

Comment: la promesa que usas no te resuelve la consulta, prueba esta solución https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500755/resolve-angular-resource-promise ,suerte!

Comment: Ya logré sacar el dato el problema ahora es por decirlo de alguna manera queda dentro de la promesa, y no puedo usarla fuera de ella..

Comment: estas **retornando** el el valor de la promesa?

Comment: ej.
 `function myFunction() {
  return api.getItem('token')
    .then(data => {
        return this.variable = data 
    }).catch((e) => console.log(`Error ${e}`))
}`

Comment: eso no me funciona, en realidad pareciera que no puedo sacar el valor de alli, eso que escribes es angular 4 el proyecto no esta en eso, esta con js esa notación ES2015 me daría error al minificar.